# How to send a email with php where the recipient address is selected from mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to send an email with PHP where the recipient address is selected from MySQL database.

Here is what I tried:

```
// Create connection
  $DBConnect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $sqlpassword, $database);

// Check connection
if ($DBConnect->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $DBConnect->connect_error);
}

  $to = "SELECT email_address FROM customer WHERE id = '$customerNum'";
  $subject = "Hello";
  $message = "Thank you!";
  $headers = "From: xxx@xxx.com";

  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);


mysqli_close($DBConnect);
```

Comment: You're not actually querying a database.  What you're looking for are introductory tutorials on using `mysqli` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

After serval tries, I manage to get it to work.
Please forgive my ignorance. I am still a beginner learner.

```
 $sql = "SELECT email_address FROM customer WHERE customer_number = $customerNum";
 $result = $DBConnect->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $to = $row["email_address"];
  }
} 
  $subject = "Hello";
  $message = "Thank you!";
  $headers = "From: xxx@xxx.com";


  mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).